# Textwatcher for my EditText is firing afterTextChanged multiple times

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I'm using `EditText` where I want to preset text or let user type something to it. I wanted to make it **"all-caps"** so I implemented capitalize function for my `TextWatcher`.

You can enter and leave screen with this `EditText` and `TextWatcher` multiple times go back and forth switching screens - that means I have to properly register and unregister `TextWatcher` from `EditText` upon screen enter/leave event.

What I noticed is, that if I enter and leave screen multiple times in a row, upon like 5th enter my whole app is frozen - so something is blocking UI Thread.

On deeper investigation I found out that if I call `editText.setText("some string")`, it will trigger my `afterTextChanged` listener multiple times. On 5th enter it triggered it like **50 times in a row** and that caused UI Thread block.

How is this fixable or is it bug on Android side?

Code:
Initializing screen on enter:

```
initEditTextListener()
App.log("FormScreen - setData")
formFirstEt?.setText(item.name)

private var inputWatcher: TextWatcher? = null
private fun initEditTextListener(){
        formFirstEt?.onEditorAction{
            formInputValidation(this.text.toString(), formFirstEt, App.getString("form_empty"), App.getString("form_empty_reason"))
            validateData()
            formSecondEt?.let { s -> if (s.isEnabled) s.requestFocus() }
        }

        inputWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                App.log("FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged")
                validateData()
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                App.log("FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged")
                validateData()
                formFirstEt?.let { et -> onFormFirstInputChanged(s.toString(), this, et)}
            }
        }

        inputWatcher?.let {formFirstEt?.addTextChangedListener(it)}
    }
```

All-Cap transformation function (should not trigger TextWatcher)

```
fun onFormFirstInputChanged(s: String, tv: TextWatcher, et: EditText) {
    et.removeTextChangedListener(tv)
    if (isFirstInputValid(s)) {
        with(et) {
            text.clear()
            append(s.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()))
            setSelection(s.length)
        }
    } else {
        val substring = s.substring(0, s.length - 1)
        with(et) {
            text.clear()
            append(substring.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()))
            setSelection(substring.length)
        }
    }
    et.addTextChangedListener(tv)
}
```

Clearing screen before leaving:

```
formFirstEt?.setText("")
inputWatcher?.let { formFirstEt?.removeTextChangedListener(it) }
inputWatcher = null
```

Logs:

```
-- First time screen enter ---
2021-01-14 11:24:50.324 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - setData
2021-01-14 11:24:50.458 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:50.460 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:52.838 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:52.841 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged

-- Second time screen enter --
2021-01-14 11:24:56.324 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - setData
2021-01-14 11:24:56.366 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.367 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.368 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.368 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.369 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.369 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.370 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.370 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.371 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - onTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.372 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.372 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
2021-01-14 11:24:56.373 1136-1136/? I/Project: FormScreen - initEditTextListener - afterTextChanged
```

**UPDATE:**
This is some Kotlin behaviour. Problem was with `formFirstEt?.setText("")` I expected it will add **empty String** to `EditText`, but apperently it is adding **character terminator**. Kotlin cant recognize that its `String` but its `char array` by default with `\0` character at the end. This char array is triggering some weird behaviour inside native `setText` function which is spamming `afterTextChanged`

Fix:

```
//type declaration String is important without it it will not work
val emptyString: String = ""
formFirstEt?.setText(emptyString)
```

Comment: I had something similar, but not sure if this is your case. My solution was to register the listener only onResume

Comment: Fix mentioned. Weird behaviour :)

Comment: @Bek Because nothing will prevent User to press Shift on keyboard and turn off capslock functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  I have a `DialogFragment` where I use a `TextInputEditText` with a watcher. If I `addTextChangedListener` in `onCreateView` (universally expected when using a `DialogFragment`), then the listener fires either once or multiple times per keystroke (at random).

Even using a local variable `watcherEnabled` to ensure that formatting the entered value doesn't retrigger the watcher fails.

Tried moving the assignment of the watcher to `onResume` instead.  This feels utterly ridiculous and wrong, but seems to have solved the issue.

Also note that the text watcher appears to be firing multiple times only when using the computer keyboard to enter text into the emulator.  When I use the emulator's keyboard, the watcher does not appear to misfire.  This COULD indicate the bug is solely with the emulator.